# How Lyman transition (to the ground state from higher excited) happens ? The dipole selection rule is +/- 1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

How are the lyman series observed when the dipole selection rule is +/-1 in l change for hydrogen atom ?

Answer (score 1):

The dipole selection rules is about angular momentum quantum number. Only principal quantum number is relevant about Lyman series.

Comment: Ok I got it is from 4p l=1 to 1s l=0 for example. Thanks.